# How to add namespace and prefix for all elements and attributes using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, namespaces

My problem is how to add namespace and prefix for all elements and attributes using XSLT?
My input xml as is....

```
<ProcessCreditMemo xmlns='CreditMemo' 
                   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
                   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                   xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<ORDER_HEADERDetails>
    <ORDER_HEADER>
    <NAME>0010185214</NAME>
```

to be...

```
<ns0:ProcessCreditMemo xmlns='CreditMemo' 
                       xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
                       xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                       xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                       xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns0:ORDER_HEADERDetails>
    <ns0:ORDER_HEADER>
   <ns0:NAME>0010185214</NAME>
```

I need add the prefix "ns0:" for all elements and attributes, and add the namespace "xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" in the header "ProcessCreditMemo".

I am trying to build a XSLT to do it...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|text()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="local-name()='ProcessCreditMemo'">
            <xsl:attribute name="xmlns" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
        </xsl:if>
```

but the resulting XML duplicates the prefix with empty value.

```
<ProcessCreditMemo xmlns="CreditMemo" 
                   xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" 
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   ns0:xmlns="">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="ns0:{name()}" namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the (corrected) provided input (severely malformed, incomplete XML)**:

```
<ProcessCreditMemo xmlns='CreditMemo'
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <ORDER_HEADERDetails>
    <ORDER_HEADER>
      <NAME>0010185214</NAME>
    </ORDER_HEADER>
  </ORDER_HEADERDetails>
</ProcessCreditMemo>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result (not the severely malformed/incomplete provided wanted-result):**

```
<ns0:ProcessCreditMemo xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="CreditMemo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns0:ORDER_HEADERDetails>
      <ns0:ORDER_HEADER>
         <ns0:NAME>0010185214</ns0:NAME>
      </ns0:ORDER_HEADER>
   </ns0:ORDER_HEADERDetails>
</ns0:ProcessCreditMemo>
```

Comment: I am using a similar code snippet in my xslt but my eclipse keeps showing error message as invalid xpath for ....  <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>  ..
However, the xml conversion is working perfectly.